# react-select with selectable group labels

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to have the group labels in react-select selectable? I want to be able to do a search, have all of the relevant items to show in addition to their group label, and be able to click and select the group label (which has it's own ID value).

Comment: Could you provide a sample of code you've already done ? or at least the kind of options you would have etc ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you are looking for.
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/2659#issuecomment-450700209

```js
loadOptions = (value) => {
    return this.getSuggestions(value).then(
      rsp => {
        const suggestions = this.filterGroupedSuggestions(rsp.data)
        const creatable = {
          label: `Search "${value}"`,
          value: value,
          group: 'search'
        }
        return [creatable, ...suggestions]
      }
    )
  }
```